# How do I find bastions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the best way to find bastions in minecraft? Because I find it annoying to randomly travel in the nether hoping to stumble across a bastion.

I tried the main method of looking for the following biomes to look for a bastion, but sometimes it takes too long:

- Crimson Forest
- Nether Wastes
- Soul Sand Valley
- Warped Forest

I also looked at the following [site](https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/how-find-minecraft-bastion-remnant), but it is not extremely fast at finding bastions.

Comment: Well, that's the joy of exploring...

Comment: Ya, but I'm looking for a fast way, e.g. during speedruns

Comment: It's not so much that the question is interesting or not, it's more about the quality, and what effort you put into first solving your problem.  Hover over the downvote arrow and the tool tip will explain: "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe because it's lacking what you've done so far to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't opposed to using an external tool, there is a nice site I use for finding both Bastions Remnants and Nether Fortresses.  It is called [Chunkbase](https://www.chunkbase.com/).

All you need to do is select which [App](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/) you want (in your case, the [Bastion app](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/bastion-remnant-finder#4670146600342495769)) and supply your world seed.  After doing so, the graph will display all the locations of where a Bastion is located for your world - all you need to do is get walking!  Note that the tool only works for more recent versions of the game, and also supports Bedrock edition.

The [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bastion_Remnant#Generation) also has a decent explanation on how these generate:

> Bastions remnants won't spawn in Basalt Deltas, but can spawn anywhere else in the Nether.

> The regions are 432×432 blocks in Java Edition and 480×480 blocks in Bedrock Edition. Each region has a 4-chunk separation located on the south and east borders of the region in which neither a fortress nor a bastion can generate. This leaves only a 368×368 block section in Java Edition or 416×416 block section in Bedrock Edition where a structure can generate. Two structures will never generate in the same region, however they might overlap if they generate close to the separation border. In Java Edition, the chance of a bastion generating instead of a fortress is 3⁄5 (60%), while in Bedrock Edition the chance of a bastion generating instead of a fortress is 2⁄3 (66.6%).

Here is a graphic from the Wiki that represents the above quote:

[image: generation graphic]

> <sub>*Nether structure generation in Java Edition. The black lines represent each region and the dots represent coordinates. Green is where they can generate and red is where they cannot.*</sub>

Comment: Do take a note that using external tools like this is forbidden if OP's trying to speedrun. [Source](https://www.speedrun.com/mc/thread/gq26u/) Quote: "*You may not use any minecraft mod or software external to minecraft that can generate a map of the seed or obtain information about the world in any way other than exploration in the created world (you cannot copy the world and explore it in another save).*"

Answer (score 2):

An extremely easy and useful method one can use, especially in speedrunning, is the f3 method.

Simply press f3, and in the top left corner of your screen you will see an entity count. Make sure your FOV is at 90 first, then start looking around slowly. If the entity count goes to around 40-50, keep looking in that area and turn your FOV all the way to 30. If your entity count is at 20-30, there is probably a bastion in that direction you are looking.

[Video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5jyW9j9GdeQ) for reference.

Comment: In the case of speedruns (as specified in the **comments** on your question), this is probably the best bet.